# Javascript написан без ошибок, но не работает

Tags: javascript

Хотел написать js для перемещения по картинке, в консоли не выдаёт ошибок, но он не работает. В чём может быть причина? Спасибо за ответ.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var image = document.getElementById('image');

var isDragging = false; // Флаг для определения, перетаскивается ли изображение
var offsetX, offsetY; // Смещение относительно начальной точки

// Обработчик события для начала перетаскивания
image.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    isDragging = true;
    offsetX = event.offsetX;
    offsetY = event.offsetY;
});

// Обработчик события для окончания перетаскивания
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDragging = false;
});

// Обработчик события для перемещения изображения
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
        // Позиция курсора мыши минус смещение
        var x = event.clientX - container.offsetLeft - offsetX;
        var y = event.clientY - container.offsetTop - offsetY;

        // Ограничение перемещения изображения в пределах контейнера
        x = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), container.clientWidth - image.width);
        y = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), container.clientHeight - image.height);

        // Установка новой позиции изображения
        image.style.left = x + 'px';
        image.style.top = y + 'px';
    }
});
```

Comment: абсолютное позиционирование картинки относительно родительского дива задано? Сделайте js-сниппет сразу, с версткой и стилями.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wsr1pt9q/
Пока не знаю как правильно здесь коммент оставлять, сделал вот так

Comment: казалось бы первое действие что вы должны были сделать для диагоностики ошибки - выводить координаты, которые присваиваете, в консоль `console.log(`${x}px, ${y}px`);` при движении мыши. там нули.

Comment: Гениально! Отпилить себе обе ноги и жаловаться, что ходить не можете... Обратите внимание на `Ограничение перемещения изображения в пределах контейнера` и после этого посмотрите на размер картинки и контейнера

Comment: Ограничение нужно изменить в js или css?